# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Socket.IO

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

So I'm having a big issue and it protans to Socket.IO and the connection. The 'host' IP along with the port number I've entered does not want to connect. I've tried adding LocalHost, the plain IP Address, along with a variety of port numbers.

PHP Code:

```
var HOST = "/";
```

I solved the issue by doing this, but in the Chrome console, I get this error:

```
socket.io-1.4.5.js:1 POST http://192.168.1.222/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LIjrKSc 404 (Not Found)
```

I have socket.io located like: template/js/new.js

I'm not entirely sure why this issue is occuring, I'm still going to do a little research, but if anyone has a solution to this, please inform me of so.

Thanks! ~mrgreen33gamer

Comment: Please share some code...